# How to transfer files using socket programming in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets

I worked on sending text messages from one device to another device using the socket programming in iOS.

I was successful in doing that, but to transfer files from one device to another device using socket programming, I have no tutorial to follow. I'm stuck.

Please help me in resolving it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do we have a demo link for text sending iPhone to android ?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *newData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]);
    int index = 0;
    int totalLen = [newData length];
    uint8_t buffer[1024];
    uint8_t *readBytes = (uint8_t *)[newData bytes];

    while (index < totalLen) {
        if ([outputStream hasSpaceAvailable]) {
            int indexLen =  (1024>(totalLen-index))?(totalLen-index):1024;

            (void)memcpy(buffer, readBytes, indexLen);

            int written = [outputStream write:buffer maxLength:indexLen];

            if (written < 0) {
                break;
            }

            index += written;

            readBytes += written;
        }
    }
```

If your NSData is big enough you need to cut it into pieces.You'll need bytes to transfer them.